# How to place strings into an array through a search and then output it?

Tags: php, regex

```
$states = "Mississippi Alabama Texas Massachusetts Kansas";
$statesA = explode(' ',$states);
$statesArray = array();

foreach($statesA as $state) {
if(preg_match( '/xas$/', trim($state)))
$statesArray[0] = trim($state);
}

foreach($statesA as $state) {
if(preg_match('/^k.*s$/i', trim($state)))
$statesArray[1] = trim($state);
}

foreach($statesA as $state) {
if(preg_match('/^M.*s$/', trim($state)))
$statesArray[2] = trim($state);
}

foreach($statesA as $state) {
if(preg_match('/a$/', trim($state)))
$statesArray[3] = trim($state);
}

foreach($statesA as $state) { #PROBLEM HERE
if(preg_match('/^M/', trim($state)))
$statesArray[4] = trim($state);
}

foreach ( $statesArray as $element => $value )
print( "Element $element of the Array is $value <br />");
```

The task is to basically to output a word that begins with the letter M in the variable state. I have `"Mississippi Alabama Texas Massachusetts Kansas"` in `$states`. When I try to print it out, `Massachusetts` gets printed out rather than `Mississippi`. Why is that?

Comment: Well, `Massachusetts` is the last element to match, overwriting the previous match of `Mississippi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?
 foreach($statesA as $state) { #PROBLEM HERE
  if(preg_match('/^M/', trim($state)))
  $statesArray[4] = trim($state);
  }
?>
```

In your code above, both Massachusetts and Mississippi match your expression, and they are both stored in `$statesArray[4]`. If you want only the first match, maybe you should also check if `$statesArray[4]` is already set. So, something like this should work:

```
<?
  foreach($statesA as $state) { #PROBLEM HERE
    if(preg_match('/^M/', trim($state)) && !isset($statesArray[4]))
    $statesArray[4] = trim($state);
  }
?>
```

This would fill `$statesArray[4]` only if it is not already set.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: That wouldn't actually accomplish anything.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: That particular expression /^M.*s$/ is to search for a word that begins with M and ends with S hence, Massachusetts. It shouldn't match  Mississippi since it does not end with S. The purpose for the last for each is to be able to print out the first word that begins with M which is Mississippi  in this case. Is the syntax wrong? Thank you for helping!

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I did not have a proper look. However the solution is the same. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Shinji: `Missisippi` and `Massachusetts` both begin with `M`. They're both matched by your expression and one is overwritten by the other.

Comment: Yes, I see your point, I have edited the wrong match and condition, but the solution is pretty much the same. Check if the variable is already filled before filling it.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kasipovic. You've saved me!